# es6 how to export native object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to extend js native object with a new function then export that function, I tried something like this

```
export Object.prototype.renameProperty = function () {
    console.log('do stuff') 
}
```

I got unexpected token error. What the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why won't you just define it as a standalone function, assign it to the object property, and export that standalone function

Comment: read the [export documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-exports)

Comment: just don't use `export` and make sure you include this before any code that uses it. Your code will work fine until you want to kill yourself.

Comment: @GershonPapi mind to give an exmaple?

Comment: Couldn't you just make a pointer which redirects to `Object.prototype.renameProperty()`

Comment: @MayorMonty how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of using modules in ES6+ is that you don't need to modify the prototypes of objects you don't own. But if you must write it this way, you'll need to either just declare the code in the file without an export:

**prototype.js**

```
Object.prototype.renameProperty = function () {
    console.log('do stuff') 
}
```

And import it like so:

```
import "./prototype.js";
```

Or if you really need to both add it to the prototype and export it, then:

**prototype.js**

```
export const renameProperty = Object.prototype.renameProperty = function () {
    console.log('do stuff') 
};
```

And import it like so:

```
import {renameProperty} from "./prototype.js";
({}).renameProperty(); // do stuff
renameProperty.bind({})(); // do stuff
```